# Rich text formatting: Setting font overwrites other settings like underline, pointsize, but fontcolors stays

Tags: python, html, qt, pyqt4

So as nobody wanted to use my running example, here is just the code for changing the font.
It does not work as it is, though I thought it should. If you uncomment the commented lines, it works. But why? Shouldn't this be the default behaviour?

```
def changeFont(self):
    cur=self.textedit.textCursor()
    if cur.hasSelection():
        begin=cur.anchor()
        end=cur.position()
        if begin>end:
            helper=end
            end=begin
            begin=helper
    else:
        cur.select(QTextCursor.Document)
        begin=0
        plainText=self.textedit.toPlainText()
        end=len(plainText)

    for i in range(begin,end):
        cur.setPosition(i)
        cur.movePosition(QTextCursor.Right, QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
        fmt=cur.charFormat()

        #pointSize=fmt.fontPointSize()

        #if fmt.fontUnderline():
        #     underline=True
        #else:
        #    underline=False
        #if fmt.fontItalic():
        #    italic=True
        #else:
        #    italic=False
        #if fmt.fontWeight()==75:
        #    bold=True
        #else:
        #    bold=False
        #if fmt.fontStrikeOut():
        #    strikeOut=True
        #else:
        #    strikeOut=False

        fmt.setFont(QFont(self.font))

        #if underline:
        #    fmt.setFontUnderline(True)
        #if italic:
        #    fmt.setFontItalic(True)
        #if bold:
        #    fmt.setFontWeight(75)
        #if strikeOut:
        #    fmt.setFontStrikeOut(True)

        #fmt.setFontPointSize(pointSize)

        cur.mergeCharFormat(fmt)
```

Answer (score 0):

With all due respect... please clarify the question and reduce the code to a minimum that demonstrates the problem.  The question seems like 'can you fix my code' and most people don't want to read so much code.

Having said that, the Qt model is: a TextCursor applies a Format to a portion of a TextDocument.  You get the format, change it, and tell the cursor to reapply it (set it or merge it).  There are several class of Format (Block, Font, etc.) that can be changed independently.  The color of the font is in its format.  You got the format (it had a color in it), you didn't change the color in the format, you reapplied the format, why SHOULD the color change?  (I didn't read your code carefully, sorry if I am misstating something.)

Comment: Ok i put the simple function there instead of the running example. I think the same way as you, but take a short look at the commented lines. With them, it works. But wasn't this the behaviour that "merge" would normally do? Seems like setting a new font removes all format...

Comment: I don't know for sure, but try cur.setCharFormat() ?  (I have been struggling with a similar problem, and the documentation doesn't make clear the difference between 'merge' and 'set'.) Maybe there is some concept of 'touched' in the a format, and merging only changes the attributes that have been 'touched' by your code.